# How to extract minute from timestamp in Big Query?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, google-bigquery, timestamp

I'm trying to extract minute from these timestamps that are in the format 2022-07-02 13:00:49 UTC.

I've tried:

```
date_diff(extract(date from SRT_cred_tmst), extract(date from rcvd_cred_tmst), Minute) as RCVD_to_SORT 
,date_diff(extract(date from Str_lod_cred_tmst), extract(date from SRT_cred_tmst), Day) as SORT_to_ST_LOAD
```

Big Query supports the "Day", but not the "Minute". Any ideas?

Comment: Try `datetime_diff`. Also, `extract(date from column)` will truncate the column to day, I think you dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, [date_diff()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff) supports any part down to day, [datetime_diff()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime_diff) supports any part down to microseconds,

To exact minute diff from two timestamps, you can use datetime_diff() function.

Here is the query:

```
datetime_diff(SRT_cred_tmst, rcvd_cred_tmst, MINUTE) as RCVD_to_SORT,
datetime_diff(Str_lod_cred_tmst, SRT_cred_tmst, DAY) as SORT_to_ST_LOAD
```